# Trying Cherry Pick in Visual Studio 2013 with Git extension tools

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to find a way to "Cherry Pick" in visual studio 2013. We do not want to merge all of our beat branch into our master branch, but only certain changes. I see it seems that only Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and newer allow this. How can I do this task in Visual Studio 2013, or what should I do to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing another tool to cherry pick. There are tools for both command line and with a graphical user interface (https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows).